# AES GCM Decrypt the text in Python which is encrypted in Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, aes-gcm

Please help on getting the equivalent decryption code in Python for below AES-GCM

```
private static final String IV = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";
private static final String IV = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static final String ALGORITHMSTR = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String DEFAULT_CODING = "utf-8";
private static final String KEY = "super secret";

private String encrypt(String valueToEnrypt) {
String encryptKey = "";
        encryptKey = KEY;
        byte[] input = valueToEncrypt.getBytes(DEFAULT_CODING);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(encryptKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String myHash = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(thedigest).toLowerCase();
        
        //System.out.println("HASH :: "+myHash);    
        SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(myHash.getBytes(), "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec ivspec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, (IV.getBytes(DEFAULT_CODING)));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHMSTR);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, ivspec);
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
        int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
}
public static String decrypt(String valueToDecrypt) throws Exception {
        String decryptKey = KEY;
        byte[] keyb = decryptKey.getBytes(DEFAULT_CODING);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(keyb);
        String myHash = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(thedigest).toLowerCase();
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(myHash.getBytes(), "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec ivspec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, (IV.getBytes(DEFAULT_CODING)));
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHMSTR);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);
        byte[] clearbyte = dcipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(valueToDecrypt));
        return new String(clearbyte, DEFAULT_CODING);
}
```

This code works fine for encryption and decryption with any key length. I need the equivalent code in Python which can decrypt the text encrypted through the above encrypt method in Java.

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow.com is not a code conversion service.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)